# datediff function resulted in an overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error :

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts
>   separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff
>   with a less precise datepart.

Was it a data issue or code issue? This is my query:

```
declare @calltime datetime

select ET.DriverID,ET.Equipid 'History',ET.Equipid       'VehicleID',ET.SignalDateTime,ET.SpeedOfTheVehicle,ET.Address,ET.IgnitionStat    us 'Inputs',ET.Ltime,ET.Currentstatus 'Status',E.EquipmentName     'Name',EG.EquipGroup 'Category',
DM.DriverName 'Driver',si.ImgPath,ET.Currentstatus,ET.Currentstatus+' '
+CONVERT (varchar ,
case when (ET.Currentstatus = 'Stopped') 
then 


convert(varchar,
DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(datetime,'1900-01-01 00:00:00'),
    CONVERT(datetime,DateAdd(ss,cast((DateDiff(ss,ET.SignalDateTime,getdate()))     as int),ET.Ltime) )))+'d  ' + 
    convert(varchar,DATEPART(HH,DateAdd(ss,cast((DateDiff(ss,ET.SignalDateTime,ge    tdate())) as int),ET.Ltime) )) +'h '+ 
   convert(varchar,DATEPART(mi,DateAdd(ss,cast((DateDiff(ss,ET.SignalDateTime,ge    tdate())) as int),ET.Ltime) )) +'m '+ 
    convert(varchar,DATEPART(ss,DateAdd(ss,cast((DateDiff(ss,ET.SignalDateTime,ge    tdate())) as int),ET.Ltime) )) +'s '
when (ET.CurrentStatus = 'NoSignal')
then 
convert(varchar,
DATEDIFF(day,ET.SignalDateTime,GETDATE()))+'d  ' + 
convert(varchar,DATEPART(HH,(GETDATE()-et.SignalDateTime))) +'h '+ 
convert(varchar,DATEPART(mi,(GETDATE()-et.SignalDateTime))) +'m '+ 
convert(varchar,DATEPART(ss,(GETDATE()-et.SignalDateTime))) +'s ' 
Else (convert(varchar,
DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(datetime,'1900-01-01 00:00:00'),
CONVERT(datetime,ET.Ltime)))+'d  ' + 
convert(varchar,DATEPART(HH,CONVERT(datetime,ET.Ltime))) +'h '+ 
convert(varchar,DATEPART(mi,CONVERT(datetime,ET.Ltime))) +'m '+ 
convert(varchar,DATEPART(ss,CONVERT(datetime,ET.Ltime))) +'s ')
end) as Status,
CONVERT(varchar,ET.SignalDateTime,101) +' '+     CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(ET.SignalDateTime AS TIME),100) Time
from tbl_EquipmentTrack ET left outer join tbl_Equipment E on E.EquipID     = ET.EquipID
inner join tbl_EquipmentGroup EG on EG.EquipGroupID = E.EquipGroupID    
left outer join tbl_DriverMaster DM on DM.driverID = ET.driverID
inner join tbl_EquipmentType ETY on E.EquipTypeID = ETY.EquipTypeID
left join tbl_SystemStatus SS on    SS.SystemStatusCode =     ET.Currentstatus and SS.StatusTypeID = 2
left outer join dbo.tbl_StatusIMG si on     ETY.EquipTypeID=si.NotificationType and si.StatusTypeID=2 and     si.SystemStatusID = SS.SystemStatusID 
where ET.CompanyID = @CompanyID
```

Comment: Did you try searching for error? There are plenty of answers about this error. Seems like there is a bug in `DateDiff` function.

Comment: Isolate the problem instead of posting everything. Although I see different issues in your script, I would prefer to solve the issue instead of rewriting your entire query

Answer (score 1):

Check the following MSDN link and look at the 'Return Value' section:

[MSDN DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

There are max values set for returning from datediff.

For example, the max difference for MILLISECONDS is:

> 24 days, 20 hours, 31 minutes and 23.647 seconds

Therefore the following statement will return the exception you see:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, DATEADD(YEAR,-5,GETDATE()), GETDATE())
```